# VBA .Find on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 4 tabs each with 200,000+ rows. The requestee of this project wants to fill 2 columns worth of data which is prospecting data - but only on the rows in which the "firm" is listed as N/A. On another tab, I have imported current hiearchy data for location and firm. I previously set up a find and replace which works fine but I am not sure of a way to limit this without using the filter feature which takes much much longer.

Examples below

**Hiearchy table used for the lookup**

| Location | Firm |
| --- | --- |
| Yon Studio | HBC |
| Daves Studio | HBC |
| Mikes Studio | Zym |
| Toads Ears | Mack |
| Yellow Labs | Zym |

**Data with blanks for the lookup**

| Artist | Location | Firm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike found | Yon Studio | N/A |
| Yellowcab | Yon Studio | HBC |
| Twim | Mikes Studio | N/A |
| Nacho Bop | Mikes Studio | N/A |
| Poof | Yellow Labs | Zym |

**Code**

```
For Each iterator In lookuprange
        
        arrayofvalues(0) = iterator.Offset(, 1).Value
        arrayofvalues(1) = iterator.Offset(, 2).Value
        arrayofvalues(2) = iterator.Offset(, 3).Value
        odict.Add key:=iterator.Value, Item:=arrayofvalues
    
Next iterator

For Each key In odict.Keys
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fnd = ws.Columns("AA:AA").Find(what:=key, lookat:=xlWhole) & ws.Columns("AC:AC").Find(what:="N/A", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
        fndfirst = fnd.Address
        Do
            fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value = (odict(key)(1))
            fnd.Offset(0, 3).Value = (odict(key)(2))
            Set fnd = ws.Columns("AA:AA").FindNext(after:=fnd)
        Loop While fnd.Address <> fndfirst
    End If
        
Next key
```

The reason why we want to limit to N/A is because that Artist could have been associated to a different firm at the time of recording vs NOW

Tried the above but it cleans everything. Tried a filter option but the run-time is ridiculous.

Comment: It's not really that clear to me exactly what you want to do here - you have 4 tabs of data, but are there other tabs?  Where does the lookup table fit in?  Maybe you can add a little more detail?

Comment: 4 tabs of data that needs to be "cleaned". 1 tab with the sitting hierarchy. The 4 tabs that need to be cleaned have roughly ~200k rows each so VBA filtering on multiple criteria does not work. I was looking for a solution similar to find to look up the locations on the hierarchy table and clean the firm column (with only N/A values) to the values found on the hierarchy table. So the table with blanks for lookup (above) should clean the N/A values with the matching values found on Hiearchy table used for the lookup

Comment: Your sample data doesn't seem to match the code though?  Eg two columns in your lookup table, but your code suggests there are at least 4.  Makes it difficult to really be sure what's going on.

Comment: Please share the tab names, the column strings or indexes, the preceding code, a screenshot of the expected result, ... etc. There just is not enough information to help you. Using the Find method with so many rows will be far too slow as will reading all the columns into the dictionary. Copy the values of the whole lookup range (4 columns) into an array. Read the lookup values (first column) into the keys of the dictionary but only the rows into the corresponding items. Copy the source values into another array and loop through it and on each match, using the dictionary, copy ...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to limit data update to only the rows where the Firm colum is listed NA, you can do this

```
For Each key In odict.Keys
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fnd = ws.Columns("AA:AA").Find(what:=key, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    ' Check if "Firm" column is "N/A" and the corresponding "Artist" is found
    If Not fnd Is Nothing And fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value = "N/A" Then
        fndfirst = fnd.Address
        Do
            fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value = (odict(key)(1))
            fnd.Offset(0, 3).Value = (odict(key)(2))
            Set fnd = ws.Columns("AA:AA").FindNext(after:=fnd)
        Loop While fnd.Address <> fndfirst
    End If
Next key
```

if checks if the Firm column value of the found Artist is NA before updating the data

Comment: this did not work. The range is already set with the find logic above two lines so the N/A essentially adds nothing.